# change number_format of whole column in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

In Python, using Openpyxl, is there a way of changing the number format of a whole column?

Currently, I'm only able to change this one cell at a time:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsxFile)
ws = wb['Tasks']
ws.cell(9, 10).number_format = u'#,##0.00€'
```

For confitional formatting, there's this simple solution using a range:

```
ws.conditional_formatting.add('I2:%s' % row, openpyxl.formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['0'], font=redFont))
```

I populate datas in this xlsx file from a python script so one cell at a time is doable but I want to change `number_format` and conditional formatting for multiple columns and hundreds of rows...

Comment: The OOXML format means that you can only ever do this one cell at a time. If necessary, create a function that helps you do this for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use:

```
col = ws.column_dimensions['A']
col.number_format = u'#,##0.00€'
```

Note that you have to apply this format to already created cells by Excel. Otherwise you have to iterate cell by cell.
Here is the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html)

Comment: do you know where is that column_dimensions in API documentation? Which module, submodule is that because I can't find it in worksheet submodule

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.html

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html

Comment: The column_dimensions is a DimensionHolder of the dimensions module

Comment: This does not work. It seems the only way to apply format is by iterating through each cell

Comment: @PriyankaJ Note that you have to apply this format to already created cells by Excel.